Why is my LDA model predicting incorrectly in R?
My LDA model is incorrectly predicting my variable with a factor level of 1 as 0. I'm not sure how to go about fixing the model.
Here is my code:
#LDA
lda.model = lda(factor(Donation) ~ Age + Home + NumberOfChild, data = dftrain)

predictions.lda = predict(lda.model, newdata = dftest)
summary(predictions.lda$class)
summary(dftest$Donation)
caret::confusionMatrix(as.factor(predictions.lda$class), as.factor(dftest$Donation))

Here is the summary:
summary(lda.model)
Length Class  Mode     
prior    2     -none- numeric  
counts   2     -none- numeric  
means   26     -none- numeric  
scaling 13     -none- numeric  
lev      2     -none- character
svd      1     -none- numeric  
N        1     -none- numeric  
call     3     -none- call     
terms    3     terms  call     
xlevels  0     -none- list   

Here were the results of the confusion matrix:
Confusion Matrix and Statistics
    Reference
Prediction     0     1
         0 27194  1430
         1     0     0
                                      
           Accuracy : 0.95            
             95% CI : (0.9475, 0.9525)
No Information Rate : 0.95            
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.507           
                                      
                  Kappa : 0               
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          
                                          
            Sensitivity : 1.00            
            Specificity : 0.00            
         Pos Pred Value : 0.95            
         Neg Pred Value :  NaN            
             Prevalence : 0.95            
         Detection Rate : 0.95            
   Detection Prevalence : 1.00            
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.50            
                                          
       'Positive' Class : 0               
                              

One thing to note is that I have added and removed variables, and the confusion matrix does not change. The dataset has over 66,000 observations.

You have a lot of terms there, is your dataset large enough to capture all of the interactions?  Maybe edit your question and post the results of summary(lda.model). I would start with a simpler model to see how that fits before adding terms.

Added suggestions

Also just lda.model is a better summary than summary(lda.model)

I am not familiar enough with LDA to provide much meaningful advice, but it looks like with only 5% of your population being donors, there are couple of possibilities. Who donates are random thus a poor model, the variables given do not predict the donors, or LDA is not the correct technique to use.  I would try plotting the donate with each individual variable to see if there are any groups. Maybe try logistic regression. Sorry this is the best advice I can provide.

I ended up rebalancing the data to create a more even amount of occurrences of donated and not donated. This gave me a better predicting model.
